# "two President Roosevelts" or "two Presidents Roosevelt?" Pluralize the honorific or the name?

Tags: grammatical-number, names, honorifics

If you have two people with the same name, affixed with the same honorific, do you pluralize the honorific or the name? For example,

> - There were two President Roosevelts.
> - There were two Presidents Roosevelt.

or *two Mister Smiths* vs. *two Misters Smith*, etc.

I'm **very** heavily leaning toward the former (*President Roosevelts*), but I need a way to explain it. Someone else is trying to argue the latter.

Comment: There were two Presidents named Roosevelt.

Comment: There is no functional difference between "the President Roosevelts" and "the brother Karamazovs."

Comment: almost a duplicate of this older question:[Family name pluralization](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7469/family-name-pluralization)

Comment: Also related:[Pluralization of names](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39150/pluralization-of-names?lq=1)

Comment: @SvenYargs Yeah, but it's "The Brothers Karamazov", or was that your point?

Comment: @Sven: I'll counter your  *The Brothers Karamazov* with *The Two Mrs. Grenvilles* and *The Two Mr. Kissels*.

Comment: Honestly I would choose one or the other based on the audience. Simpler audiences would hear "two president Roosevelts," while more sophisticated audiences would hear "two presidents Roosevelt."

Comment: Is there a difference in a fantasy setting when an individual is duplicated? In _What are Little Girls Made Of_ or _The Enemy Within_, when duplicates are made of James T Kirk, I would say there are "two Captain Kirks." In the 2009 film _Star Trek_ where we have Captain George Kirk (Chris Hemsworth) and Captain James Kirk (Chris Pine,) I would say we have "two Captains Kirk."

Comment: @PeterShor: If _Captains Courageous_ were about Captain Emile Courageous and Captain Pierre Courageous, we'd be tied at two examples each.

Comment: @SvenYargs There is a difference: “President Roosevelt” is a title. Unless the Karamazovs were monks, you wouldn't address either as “Brother Karamazov. Rather, I think “brothers Karamazov” is an instance of putting the adjective after the noun, like “attorneys general.”

Comment: If Alyosha had stuck it out at Father Zosima's monastary, he certainly would have been Brother Alexei, but no one is likely to think of Ivan, Nikolai, or Smerdyakov as candidates for a devotional life.

Comment: *Brothers Karamazov* is simply a wooden  translation of the Russian. The idiomatic English translation is *[(The) Karamazov Brothers](http://www.amazon.com/Karamazov-Brothers-Oxford-Worlds-Classics-ebook/dp/B008C80UIY)*.

Comment: Two Roosevelt presidents

Comment: @AlanCarmack: How about the [Brothers Grimm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brothers_Grimm)? Or the [Brothers Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brothers_Johnson)?

Comment: I've never heard of a "Roosevelt president", what type of president is that?  There have also been two President Bushes... but what if their surname had been *Smiths* how would you pluralize that? Two President Smithses?! :)

Answer (score 2):

Since we're not primarily looking at constructs such as *governor general* where there are no names mentioned, let's ignore these.

For the form *(Title) (Name)*, taking personal preferences seems to lead to a rather polarising discussion. Let's instead look first at accepted conventions with other titles, specifically *Mr* and the null title.

Before looking at two individuals called *Mr X*, consider two people, *Mr X* and *Mr Y*.

The plural of *Mr* is *Messrs* according to [the Merriam Webster online dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Messrs.). See also the more extensive article on the same subject in their [Learner's Dictionary website](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/plural-form-of-mr-and-mrs). In both places, the form used to refer collectively to *Mr X* and *Mr Y* is *Messrs X and Y*. (The [female version](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mesdames) of *Messrs* is *Mesdames*, with more discussion [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/311376/142322).)

This might suggest that the form to use is *Presidents Roosevelt*, but we need to look more carefully. Where two people are both called *Mr Smith*, for example, they are *both* named using the form *Messrs Smith and Smith*. Here's an example (emphasis mine; emphases in original dropped):

> In his monthly report to the Church Envoy in February 1915, Rev JL Mortimer commented that the window was executed by *Messrs Smith and Smith*, of Dunedin.
>   [- Holy Cross, St Kilda](http://holycrossstkilda.weebly.com/brock-windows.html)

This is therefore poor support for using the *two Presidents Roosevelt* form, as supported by the ngram analysis below.

Looking now at what we might call the null title, we find that if we have two people, both called *Smith*, it is customary to call them the *Smiths*. See also the post [Family name pluralisation](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/7469/142322). Extrapolating this to your question's context produces the form *two President Roosevelts*.

Nevertheless, these are both somewhat awkward extrapolations, so let's check them against actual usage, using the 41st and 43rd US Presidents, each referred to as *President Bush*.

Looking at these forms in [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Presidents%20Bush%2CPresident%20Bushes&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CPresidents%20Bush%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BPresidents%20Bush%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpresidents%20Bush%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CPresident%20Bushes%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2CPresidents%20Bush%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BPresidents%20Bush%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpresidents%20Bush%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2CPresident%20Bushes%3B%2Cc0), we find that *Presidents Bush* is significantly more popular. When we dig deeper, though, we find that many references are to phrases like ["Presidents Bush and Obama"](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=BKOeCgAAQBAJ&pg=PP1&dq=%22presidents%20bush%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqirn-kv7LAhUFJqYKHfTGBiUQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22presidents%20bush%22&f=false), which isn't relevant here. There is only [one relevant instance](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=VbFEaef6YKQC&pg=PA383&dq=%22presidents%20bush%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqirn-kv7LAhUFJqYKHfTGBiUQ6AEIPzAH#v=onepage&q=%22presidents%20bush%22&f=false) in the first two pages of listings, and that is a piece of fiction.

The relevant references using the form *President Bushes* are more numerous and in more serious writing. Here's an example (emphasis mine):

> In the two most recent Gulf War conflicts, the weight of popular opinion led *both President Bushes* to seek congressional authorization for the invasions of Iraq in 1991 and 2003.
>   [- Kenneth Dautrich and David A Yalof, American Government](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=97HjQEgmxp0C&pg=PA212&dq=%22president%20bushes%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRsIK4l_7LAhVJl5QKHT-_BwEQ6AEINDAE#v=onepage&q=%22president%20bushes%22&f=false)

You ask:

> If you have two people with the same name, affixed with the same honorific, do you pluralize the honorific or the name?

Based on the above, the standard convention is to **pluralise the name.**

Answer (score 0):

The guide here is that when you have a set phrase ([including titles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective#Plurals_of_expressions_with_postpositives)) made from a noun and a postpositive adjective, the noun takes the plural for the very good reasons that adjectives are invariable. Hence we get professors emeritus, attorneys general, poets laureate, and so on. This can be visualised as having two professors who are emeritus ones; two attorneys who are general ones; or two poets who are laureate ones.

In the OP example, *Roosevelt* is not an adjective. It is a noun, and able to take a plural on its own, so we can have two President Roosevelts without any problems. Visualise this as having two 'President Roosevelt's . While you could also say we have two presidents, you couldn't say they are Roosevelt ones.

Answer (score -1):

The way I would explain it is by looking at the nominal group structure.

**There were two President Roosevelts**

The identified in this simple sentence is the nominal group **two president Roosevelts**

**two** gives us the number (how many?)
**President** classifies/identifies the main thing (what type?)
**Roosevelts** is the main thing in the group and, as such, can be counted (what/who?)

Epithets (describers)/Classifiers cannot be counted in English

e.g.

two running shoes = number (how many?) + classifier (what type?) + head thing (what?)
a twenty-two year old man = article/Which one (indefinite) + epithet/describer (22-year-old) + head thing (who?)

Compare this to

I am 22 years old = here, I see the main thing as "years", which, as the head thing, can be counted.

You could also point to style guides e.g. the Guardian

**attorney general**

**lc, no hyphen; plural attorney generals (there will be those who tell you it should be “attorneys general”

http://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-a

Comment: I downvoted because the last paragraph seems quite unrelated to the Original poster's question. What has "berks" and "wankers" got to do with whether one pluralizes the title *President*, or  their *last names*? E.g. "We've had two President Bushes" and "We've had two presidents that were called Bush" seem to me both correct.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for highlighting the irrelevancy. I only included it as it was a link in the original source. I have edited accordingly. However, does that make my answer irrelevant? The grammatical explanation still stands. The explanation of "2 president bushes" makes "bushes" the countable noun, while "two presidents called Bush" makes "presidents" the countable noun.

Comment: But not "We've had two president Bushes".  The pluralization of Bush or Roosevelt hinges on treating President X as a compound noun, whereas attorney general has, until recently, treated attorney as a noun and general as an adjective (i.e., attorneys general), general being a classification of attorney as opposed to attorney being a type of general.

Comment: @Egox  I am pluralizing "President Bush", If I were to say "The two President Bushes were father and son, respectively", would that be an ungrammatical sentence? If so, you have to prove it!

Comment: @Mari-LouA I agree entirely with your comment on "President Bushes".  As an addendum, I posited that the capital "P" is essential in order to treat "President Bush" as one would treat "soup bowl", in that "We've had two president" (lower case "p") results in "two presidents named Bush".

Answer (score -2):

I think the answer is obvious.

Would you say "There were two Presidents named Roosevelt" or "There were two President named Roosevelts"? Similarly, would you say "There were more than one Presidents named George" or "There was one President named George"?  The honorific is a red herring, perhaps.