# Is it okay to say "Captains Carter and Marvel"?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, titles

An artist wrote "Captains Carter and Marvel" to refer to both Captain Carter and Captain Marvel together.

Is it okay to use the title only once and make it plural when there are multiple people with that title mentioned in the sentence? Can I see some other examples?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: For example: *Messrs Moony, Wormtail, Padfoot and Prongs*

Comment: I don't remember Captain Marvel appearing in *Stargate.*

Comment: Captain Marvel was 1950s and Captain Carter was 1900s. They'd look good together, though.

Answer (score 2):

I just chose two generic names and searched for [Captains Smith and Jones](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22captains+smith+and+jones%22). Plenty of examples.

This is a perfectly normal construction, and can be extended to *Messrs* (pronounced *messers,* plural of *Mister*), *Misses, Sisters, Brothers, Sergeants, Presidents...* Where there is a title, it can be pluralised.

*Mrs* is difficult. While one might mention unmarried sisters as "The Misses Bulstrode" (or whatever), *Mrs* doesn't lend itself to pluralisation.

Comment: I've seen "the Mrs." attempted, in bad fiction, but nobody talks like that anymore.

Comment: I thought the plural of *Mrs* was *Mmes*. [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/311374) has newspaper citations that use it in its spelled-out form.